# Backbone edit or delete user

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Considering that I am new to Backbone I have managed to build my first Backbone app which at the moment it only lists people and their nationality based on a local json file:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        Name: '',
        Country:''
    }
});

var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Person,
  url: 'users.json'
});

var PersonList = Backbone.View.extend ({
  el: '.inner',
  initialize: function () {
    var people = new PersonCollection(),
        that = this;
    people.fetch({
      success: function (PersonCollection) {
        var template = _.template($('#people-template').html(), {PersonCollection: PersonCollection.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    })
  }
});

var GeneratePersonList = new PersonList();
```

I would like to be able to edit/update a single user. What would be the best way of doing that? It would be nice to have some code example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be to sync changes to your models if you are loading them from a flat json file.

If you want to avoid using a server/db to persist your data, my suggestion would be to use the [Backbone LocalStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) plugin, load some dummy data into local storage, and work with your models from there.

Here's a very loose idea of how you would do that:

```
// model ...

// (assuming you've loaded localStorage plugin on your page with underscore and backbone)
var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Person,
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("PersonCollection"), // Unique name within your app.
});

// view ...

// "bootstrap" data in to localStorage, if it is not there already
if (typeof localStorage["PersonCollection"] === 'undefined') { 
   // make ajax request, load your json into local storage 
   $.getJSON('users.json', function (data) {
       localStorage['PersonCollection'] = data;
       init();
   });
} else {
  init();
}

function init () {
  var GeneratePersonList = new PersonList();
}
```

Comment: the init () doesn't get called. I have put a console.log('here') and I can see that in the console but init() doesn't work..

Comment: @Alex does your console tell you anything else about the ajax request? I'm assuming its either a path or an issue with the way you are serving the files. Are you using a webserver?

Comment: this is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/rUdTs/ I am only using mamp to view the files as eventually I will use some php and want to test it locally..

Comment: That fiddle does not include Backbone, Underscore, or the LocalStorage plugin. My guess would be that the ``success`` function of ``$.getJSON`` is not firing because something is wrong with the request for your json file. As per my earlier comment, are you using a webserver?

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry but I am not using a web server, all the libraries are loading correctly as I can see from my network tab

Comment: `typeof localStorage["PersonCollection"] == "undefined"`

Comment: @thibauts great catch!